# jquery adding divs twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a jquery function that adds a div along with fields inside it. First time I click it, it adds one div but when I click second time it adds two divs and it should only add one.

What I am doing, is that I am counting the divs and then adding 1 and then attaching new count along with ids of fields. Can anyone check and tell why this is giving unexpected behaviour?

```js
$(".add_product").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var div_count = $(".product_fields").length;
  alert(div_count);
  var new_div_count = (div_count + 1);
  $(".product_fields").append('<div class="product_divs"><div class="product_fields"><h5>Item ' + new_div_count + '</h5><div class="input-field"><input type="text" id="item_name_"' + new_div_count + '" name="item_name[]" required><label for="item_name_1">Item Name</label></div><div class="row"><div class="col s4"><div class="input-field"><input type="text" id="item_quantity_"' + new_div_count + '" name="item_quanity[]" required><label for="item_quantity_1">Item Quantity</label></div></div><div class="col s4"><div class="input-field"><input type="text" id="item_cost_price_"' + new_div_count + '" name="item_cost_price[]" required><label for="item_cost_price_1">Item Cost Price</label></div></div><div class="col s4"><div class="input-field"><input type="text" id="item_retail_price_"' + new_div_count + '" name="item_retail_price[]"><label for="item_retail_price_1">Item Retail Price</label></div></div></div></div></div>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col s7 product_field_div">
  <div class="product_divs">
    <div class="product_fields">
      <h5>Item 1</h5>
      <div class="input-field">
        <input type="text" id="item_name_1" name="item_name[]" required>
        <label for="item_name_1">Item Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s4">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" id="item_quantity_1" name="item_quanity[]" required>
            <label for="item_quantity_1">Item Quantity</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s4">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" id="item_cost_price_1" name="item_cost_price[]" required>
            <label for="item_cost_price_1">Item Cost Price</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s4">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" id="item_retail_price_1" name="item_retail_price[]">
            <label for="item_retail_price_1">Item Retail Price</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="action_div"><a href="#" class="add_product">Add new product</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the HTML you are appending not matching the pattern of the original HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only be appending new products, not the container `div` elements as well. This is throwing your counter off.

Also (just a side note). You should not use HTML heading elements (`h1`...`h6`) because of the way they make the text look. That is the job of CSS. Use headings to denote sequential sections and sub-sections.

Lastly, only use `<a>` elements when you want navigation. If you need something to click on to trigger an action, just about any element supports a `click` event. In the code below, the `a` has been removed and just the `div` is the clickable thing. This also eliminates the need for `e.preventDefault()`.

```js
$(".add_product").click(function(e) {

  var new_div_count = ++$(".product").length;
  
  // You only want to be appending a new product, not .product_divs or .product_fields
  
  $(".product_fields").append('<h1 class="product">Item ' + new_div_count + '</h1><div class="input-field"><input type="text" id="item_name_"' + new_div_count + '" name="item_name[]" required><label for="item_name_1">Item Name</label></div><div class="row"><div class="col s4"><div class="input-field"><input type="text" id="item_quantity_"' + new_div_count + '" name="item_quanity[]" required><label for="item_quantity_1">Item Quantity</label></div></div><div class="col s4"><div class="input-field"><input type="text" id="item_cost_price_"' + new_div_count + '" name="item_cost_price[]" required><label for="item_cost_price_1">Item Cost Price</label></div></div><div class="col s4"><div class="input-field"><input type="text" id="item_retail_price_"' + new_div_count + '" name="item_retail_price[]"><label for="item_retail_price_1">Item Retail Price</label></div></div></div>');

});
```

```css
/* Use the proper heading ranks but style them any way you want. */
.product { font-size:.75em; font-weight:bold; }

/* Make the "Add product" div look like a link without having a link */
.add_product {
  cursor:pointer;
  text-decoration:underline; 
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col s7 product_field_div">
  <div class="product_divs">
    <div class="product_fields">
      <h1 class="product">Item 1</h1>
      <div class="input-field">
        <input type="text" id="item_name_1" name="item_name[]" required>
        <label for="item_name_1">Item Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s4">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" id="item_quantity_1" name="item_quanity[]" required>
            <label for="item_quantity_1">Item Quantity</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s4">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" id="item_cost_price_1" name="item_cost_price[]" required>
            <label for="item_cost_price_1">Item Cost Price</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s4">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" id="item_retail_price_1" name="item_retail_price[]">
            <label for="item_retail_price_1">Item Retail Price</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="add_product">Add new product</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're appending `<div class="product_fields">` causing length to increase by 1 each time.

Comment: He's also appending `product_divs`, which he shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Take `product_divs` and `product_fields` off the append and add a different class.

```js
$(".add_product").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var div_count = $(".fish").length + 1;
  alert(div_count);
  var new_div_count = (div_count + 1);
  $(".product_fields").append('<div class="fish"><h5>Item ' + new_div_count + '</h5><div class="input-field"><input type="text" id="item_name_"' + new_div_count + '" name="item_name[]" required><label for="item_name_1">Item Name</label></div><div class="row"><div class="col s4"><div class="input-field"><input type="text" id="item_quantity_"' + new_div_count + '" name="item_quanity[]" required><label for="item_quantity_1">Item Quantity</label></div></div><div class="col s4"><div class="input-field"><input type="text" id="item_cost_price_"' + new_div_count + '" name="item_cost_price[]" required><label for="item_cost_price_1">Item Cost Price</label></div></div><div class="col s4"><div class="input-field"><input type="text" id="item_retail_price_"' + new_div_count + '" name="item_retail_price[]"><label for="item_retail_price_1">Item Retail Price</label></div></div></div></div>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col s7 product_field_div">
  <div class="product_divs">
    <div class="product_fields">
      <h5>Item 1</h5>
      <div class="input-field">
        <input type="text" id="item_name_1" name="item_name[]" required>
        <label for="item_name_1">Item Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s4">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" id="item_quantity_1" name="item_quanity[]" required>
            <label for="item_quantity_1">Item Quantity</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s4">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" id="item_cost_price_1" name="item_cost_price[]" required>
            <label for="item_cost_price_1">Item Cost Price</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s4">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" id="item_retail_price_1" name="item_retail_price[]">
            <label for="item_retail_price_1">Item Retail Price</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="action_div"><a href="#" class="add_product">Add new product</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Istead of
`$(".product_fields").append`

use `$(".product_field_div > .action_div").before`